# FAIL - Application already exists at path /Teste

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, ide

Boa noite! Estou tendo problemas com o TomCat e o NetBeans, ele segue com a seguinte mensagem de erro?

```
Implantação em andamento...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext5869996979793086537.xml&path=/Teste
FAIL - Application already exists at path /Teste
```

Saberiam me dizer qual o problema? Ja reiniciei diversas vezes o tomcat porem nada adianta.
Estou utilizando o linux Mint e a versao 8.2 da IDE.

Comment: Parece que o Tomcat está travado. Reiniciar o netbeans nem sempre adianta porque o Tomcat executa em um processo independente.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Infelizmente nao e isso, reiniciei o pc e nada de funcionar, acaba ficando nesse mesmo erro.